# Upload de imagem e atualizar

Tags: java, tomcat, upload, file-upload, intellij-idea

Tenho uma aplicação em javaEE onde um dos requisitos é o upload de uma imagem usada para o perfil do usuário.

Tudo que está realizando até o momento:
 1. Seleciona a imagem para ser editada (Cortar, Girar e etc);
 2. A foto é passada como base64 para o Servlet;
 3. A imagem é convertida em arquivo png e salva em um diretório [media/pic/example-img-hash-name.png];
 4. Salva o nome da imagem no banco de dados referente ao usuário;
 5. Retorna o nome da imagem e troca o atributo "src" da imagem com javascript;

Até aí tudo bem, porém a imagem não atualiza. Tento também acessar a imagem pelo link e não consigo. Somente depois que reinicio o servidor a nova imagem é carregada.

Isso é alguma configuração do servidor? web.xml?
Estou usando IntelliJ IDEA + Tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No atributo SRC da TAG IMG, insira uma variável que chamamos de identificador "no-cache".
gere um numero randomico que mudará a cada requisição. Assim o cache tanto do navegador, quanto do servlet, não irão responder o cache e sim a consulta correta.

EX:

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!